# dplyr method to check two levels of association

Tags: r, dplyr

I don't know the correct term for what I am trying to do. I have a hierarchy of parent/child terms:

```
37─┐
   ├─38
   ├─45─┐
   │    ├─19
   │    └─89
   └─88
```

I also have a data frame with information about each term:

```
tmp <- structure(
  list(
    id = c(88, 89, 19, 38, 45, 37),
    parent_id = c(37, 45, 45, 37, 37, NA), 
    other_info = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
  ),
  row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 18L),
  class = "data.frame"
)
```

I want to add a column indicating whether each term is a "grandchild", i.e., if it's parent has a parent. I can do this with a `for` loop as follows:

```
grandchild <- vector()

for (i in 1:nrow(tmp)) {
  parent <- tmp[i, 2]
  if (is.na(parent)) {
    grandchild <- c(grandchild, FALSE)
    next
  }
  grandparent <- tmp[tmp$id == parent, 2]
  grandchild <- c(grandchild, !is.na(grandparent))
}

tmp$grandchild <- grandchild
```

This give the desired output:

```
   id parent_id other_info grandchild
1  88        37          a      FALSE
2  89        45          b       TRUE
3  19        45          c       TRUE
5  38        37          d      FALSE
6  45        37          e      FALSE
18 37        NA          f      FALSE
```

However, I would like to avoid the `for` loop and would ideally like to use `dplyr`. Is there a way to do this using `dplyr`? I tried the following using `case_when`, but it doesn't give the expected result:

```
tmp2 <- tmp %>% 
  {dplyr::mutate(., grandchild = dplyr::case_when(
    is.na(parent_id)                    ~ FALSE, 
    is.na(.[.[["id"]] == parent_id, 2]) ~ FALSE, 
    TRUE                                ~ TRUE
  ))}
```

Thanks.

**Edit based on accepted answer:**
Using Allan Cameron's answer, this code using `case_when` also works. For the original question, this is a lot of unnecessary typing, but in cases where a more complex new column is desired, this may be useful.

```
tmp2 <- tmp %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(grandchild = dplyr::case_when(
    is.na(parent_id[match(parent_id, id)]) ~ FALSE, 
    TRUE                                   ~ TRUE
  ))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```r
tmp %>% mutate(grandchild = !is.na(parent_id[match(parent_id, id)]))
#>    id parent_id other_info grandchild
#> 1  88        37          a      FALSE
#> 2  89        45          b       TRUE
#> 3  19        45          c       TRUE
#> 5  38        37          d      FALSE
#> 6  45        37          e      FALSE
#> 18 37        NA          f      FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: `match`, a new tool for my toolbox!